# Rails: Join arrays from two queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm sorry to ask a stupid question. I've got an array that I want to populate with two similar queries to my database.

```
@experience_items = @user.experience_items.where(current: true).order(start_date: :desc)
@experience_items << @user.experience_items.where(current: false).order(end_date: :desc)
```

This is currently returning an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`, which I can't iterate through with `<% @experience_items.each do |item| %>`

I know this is basic, but I just don't understand it. Why can't I iterate through @experience_items?

Comment: You should. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @Arup: I was getting an error as it was trying to find a (missing) field on the relation object itself, not on each item in the list

Comment: Ok.. Cool. Please next time add the _exception_ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you add `ActiveRecord::Relation` to `@experience_items` as an element instead of concatenating these array-like objects. This should work:

```
@experience_items += @user.experience_items.where(current: false).order(end_date: :desc)
```

Comment: @WillTaylor how about this "in a minute"? :)